# How can I parse a string with double curly brackets, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a fast regex method or similar that can take a string and parse it into bits **not** in double-curly brackets (let's call those "static") and bits that **are** in double-curly brackets (let's call those "dynamic")?

For example, input:

```
Lorem {{ipsum dolor sit}} amet, {consectetur} adipiscing {{elit}}.
```

Required output:

```
[
  {
    type: "static",
    value: "Lorem "
  },
  {
    type: "dynamic",
    value: "ipsum dolor sit"
  },
  {
    type: "static",
    value: " amet, {consectetur} adipiscing "
  },
  {
    type: "dynamic",
    value: "elit"
  },
  {
    type: "static",
    value: "."
  },
]
```

My best try so far has been to use `/\{*([^{}]+)\}*/g` as a regex and loop through using `while` and `exec` but it incorrectly identifies *any* number of curly brackets as dynamic values, as shown here:

```js
function templateParser(string) {
  const re = /\{*([^{}]+)\}*/g;

  const output = [];

  while (true) {
    const match = re.exec(string);

    if (!match) {
      break;
    }

    const [templateItem, templateKey] = match;

    output.push({
      type: templateItem === templateKey ? "static" : "dynamic",
      value: templateItem === templateKey ? templateItem : templateKey
    });
  }

  return output;
}

console.log(
  templateParser(
    "Lorem {{ipsum dolor sit}} amet, {consectetur} adipiscing {{elit}}."
  )
);
```

Comment: there doesn't exist a pre-existing method. please share a [mcve] of something you've already tried.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sure, I've edited the question and included the code I'm currently using. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to parse it so that dynamic bits can be wrapped with certain JSX tags, and static bits in other JSX tags... which are different depending on the context, hence why I need a generic parser. @dqhendricks it doesn't look like that regex works, unfortunately.

Comment: Is there an escaping syntax available that you'll have to accommodate?  For example, how does one insert a literal `{` into the text?

Comment: What about `Lorem {{{{ipsum}}}} dolor \} \{{{sit}}\}?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To distinguish `{{` `this`  `}}` from `that` an idea to [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `this` but *match* `that`.

```
{{(.*?)}}|.+?(?={{|$)
```

- The left side of the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) *captures* "dynamic" matches to the *first group*.
- On the right side "static" parts get matched [until the next](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `{{` or up to [the end](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lsIkEo/1) or the [JS-demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##TY/BbsMgDIbvPIUnTQK2LN1u01CWF9gbTD0g4mW0ECIgWSvKs2dQ9dCT5c@frd8HucqgvJ7jy/q@bQYjhOihA/rlPFpISc9hsTA44zwEHXMGaTE2kJSbAqqIcfGFDXrWQelpLCtoqtdSQUg96HHEUzm5S4m1Tz3P@dI@96zvUro88t0oyN@vNgiM2e7qtnhCxUoOzh@6aTGGk0QA9A8w@/22vzGoDOBYww7nSVqtqIC1tFUSZZgBTcB7L0QZ77TXvQCoIrmW@pEz2Bo3MhrPM0L3SRs4NkA/YJVmuYGVC5K37R8)

Using `exec` your values can easily be set according e.g. `m[1]!=null` (*first group* matched). Of course this is related to your sample data. Assuming there is no nesting and not guessing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: the other answer deserves the credit for using positive lookahead. Using that regex, the complete solution would be:

```js
Array.from(s.matchAll(/{{(.*?)}}|.+?(?={{|$)/g))
  .map(e=>({type: e[1] ? 'dynamic' : 'static', value: e[1] ?? e[0]}))
```

or using named capturing groups:

```js
Array.from(s.matchAll(/{{(?<dynamic>.*?)}}|(?<static>.+?)(?={{|$)/g))
  .flatMap(e=>Object.entries(e.groups))
  .filter(e=>e[1]).map(e=>({type: e[0], value: e[1]}))
```

Previous answer:

```js
let s = `Lorem {{ipsum dolor sit}} amet, {consectetur} adipiscing {{elit}}.`;
let result = [{a: 0, b: 0}, ...Array.from(s.matchAll(/{{.*?}}/g))
  .map(e=>({a: e.index, b: e.index+e[0].length}))]
  .map((e, i, arr) => [
    {type: 'dynamic', a: e.a, b: e.b},
    {type: 'static', a: e.b, b: i===arr.length-1 ? s.length : arr[i+1].a}
  ])
  .flat().map(o=>({type: o.type, value: s.substring(o.a, o.b)}))
  .filter(e=>e.value.length>0)
  .map(o=>o.type==='static' ? o :
    {type: 'dynamic', value: o.value.substring(2, o.value.length-2)});
```

What this does is find all of the strings contained within double braces, and then maps them to an array of objects with start and end indices `a` and `b`.

Those will be the dynamic ranges. We then fill in the gaps in the array to get the static ranges.

Finally, we clear the empty ranges and trim the double braces from the dynamic strings.

Comment: Thanks. By the looks of it, this relies on there always being two dynamic parts, where there could be any amount or zero.

Comment: @WillStone The base case is that it will treat an empty string as starting with an empty dynamic range followed by an empty static range. That's just to make processing the string easier - the empty ranges are removed later. Then, depending on whether there are any dynamic ranges present, it will cover those cases too. It was tested on a variety of strings, and will work no matter how many dynamic ranges or how many static ranges there are.

Answer (score -1):

Now that I know more about what you are trying to do, this may help:

```
let mystring = 'test {{hello}} goodbye {{foo}} bar {foobar}';
let regex = /{{(.*?)}}/g;

console.log( mystring.match( regex ) );
```

output

```
["{{hello}}", "{{foo}}"]
```

it does a lazy match of each string that has double brackets, puts the matches in an array. You could then replace those substrings with modified versions that include the jsx tags, or something similar.

https://jsfiddle.net/u7gkz341/

Edit:

```js
let mystring = 'test {{hello}} goodbye {{foo}} bar {foobar}';
let regex = /{{(.*?)}}/g;
let match;
let lastMatchIndex = 0;
let results = [];

while ( ( match = regex.exec( mystring ) ) !== null ) {
    results.push( mystring.substring( lastMatchIndex, match.index ) ); // adds static content up until match
    results.push( match[1] ); // adds dynamic matched content
    lastMatchIndex = regex.lastIndex;
}
results.push( mystring.substring( lastMatchIndex ) ); // adds static remainder of string
console.log( results );
```

Comment: Thank you but this only matches the strings in curly brackets. Im looking to produce output as shown in my example where both static and dynamic parts are selected and the order is preserved. This allows for the data to be mapped over in JSX.

Comment: @WillStone Okay, I made an edit. You should be able to figure it out from there.